# Play Line-IN Audio in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Couldn't find anything all over the internet. If I did find something, it was only for older versions of Ubuntu and my version is 14.04. I can use the Line-In feature in Windows without any help from any 3rd party software.

Answer (score 0):

built-in:

```
    pactl load-module module-loopback
```

or, try ecasound:

```
    sudo apt-get install ecasound
    ecasound -i alsa -o alsa
```